# ROS and PyCharm integration in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pycharm, ros

I am trying to get my Pycharm to recognize ROS melodic installed on my computer. This has been asked before but the solutions provided are not working. Generally something along this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/204326/pycharm-setup/) works but this time around, it is not working.

To break down the issues:

- When I create a desktop entry, I can open PyCharm by double-clicking it. But as soon as I edit

  ```
  Exec="home/$USER/pycharm-community-2020.3/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
  ```

to

```
Exec=bash -i -c "/home/$USER/pycharm-community-2020.3/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
```

it no longer responds.

- Since this is also the solution they propose for integrating PyCharm with ROS, it doesn't work for me.
- I also looked at the paths of the interpreter I am using and it comes up like this:

  ```
  /opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python3.6/usr/lib/python3.6
  /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
  /home/$USER/working_directory/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
  ```

How do I make my PyCharm installation recognize ROS packahes such as rospy, rosbag, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you should set python2.7 as Python Interpreter. ROS use system interpreter python with its own dist-packages. For melodic, that is system python2.7.

What you should try first, open up a terminal:

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
bash /home/$USER/pycharm-community-2020.3/bin/pycharm.sh
```

Then set pycharm interpreter to system python 2.7(File->settings->Project:xxx->Python Interpreter->Python2.7),if there is no python 2.7,just click setting icon ->add -> navigate to `/usr/bin/python2.7`
try `import rospy` now, it should works out fine.

Comment: To add to this, to verify that ROS is indeed using its own dist-packages, run `echo $PYTHONPATH`, which should return the directory where all packages that are used by the default interpreter are available.